# sqlite not recognizing generic list

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store

On a windows store app project i get a JSON from a webservice that looks like this:http://paste2.org/jfMJ2AGA

and i  have these 2 classes

```
public class media
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string video { get; set; }
    public string snapshot { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string snapshot_url { get; set; }
}

public class artigos
{
    public string menu { get; set; }
    public string submenu { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string subtitle { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<media> media { get; set; }
}
```

and im creating a sqlite database with:

```
dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.sqlite");

//start dB
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    db.CreateTable<artigos>();
}
```

but i get this error:

> Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xxxxx.media]

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: it has been a while, but if i recall i think i saved a json string with media objects ids, something like  [
"1234","5678","9012","3456"
]

Comment: That's exactly the approach I was going to take. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqllite does not support lists. This means that you can´t have

```
public List<media> media { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an int[] and I did this:

```
[Table(nameof(Folder))]
public class Folder
{
    public Folder()
    {
        // for SQLite
    }
    internal Folder(Json.Folder folder)
    {
        Id = folder.id;
        Title = folder.title;
        Lists = string.Join(",", folder.list_ids);
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Lists { get; set; }
    public int[] ListsArray => Lists.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
}
```